# Is integral of greater function still greater?

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

If I have $f(x) \geq g(x) $ for all $x$ over $[a;b]$, does it imply that $\int_a^b f(x)dx \geq \int_a^b g(x)dx$?
Or should any other requirements be added? Such as $f(x)$ should be convex or positive, etc...

Comment: No other condition necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $h(x):=f(x)-g(x)$ so $h\ge0$, and your desired conclusion is $\int_a^bhdx\ge0$. Indeed, this integral is an increasing function of $b$ that's $0$ if $b=a$, and so is $\ge0$ for all $b\ge a$.

Answer (score 1):

The definite integral operator is linear, so

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\ge\int_a^b g(x)\,dx\iff\int_a^b (f(x)-g(x))\,dx\ge0.$$

Then

$$f(x)\ge g(x)\implies f(x)-g(x)\ge 0$$ and the integral of a non-negative function cannot yield a negative result.